# How to sort each column of matrix with R function?

Tags: r, matrix, apply

Do you know an R function that sort each column of a matrix without using apply like this:

```
mat= matrix(c(1,2,0,-7,-4,7,8,3,12,15,23,-21),nrow = 4,ncol = 3)
apply(mat,2,sort)
##
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   -7   -4  -21
[2,]    0    3   12
[3,]    1    7   15
[4,]    2    8   23
```

Do you also know a R function that return a vector of max of each column of a matrix without using apply like this?

```
mat2=matrix(c(2,1,0,-7,-4,7,8,3,12,15,23,-21),nrow = 3,ncol = 4)
apply(mat2,2,max)
##
[1]  2  7 12 23
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are against the apply function? Is it just this particular function or all *apply family functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to avoid using `*apply` family, here are several alternatives you can try

- `order` method

```
> `dim<-`(mat[order(col(mat), mat)], dim(mat))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   -7   -4  -21
[2,]    0    3   12
[3,]    1    7   15
[4,]    2    8   23

> `dim<-`(mat2[order(col(mat2), -mat2)], dim(mat2))[1, ]
[1]  2  7 12 23
```

- `ave` method

```
> ave(mat, col(mat), FUN = sort)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   -7   -4  -21
[2,]    0    3   12
[3,]    1    7   15
[4,]    2    8   23


> unique(ave(mat2, col(mat2), FUN = max))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    7   12   23

> ave(mat2, col(mat2), FUN = max)[1, ]
[1]  2  7 12 23
```

- `aggregate` method

```
> `dim<-`(unlist(aggregate(mat, list(rep(1, nrow(mat))), sort)[-1]), dim(mat))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   -7   -4  -21
[2,]    0    3   12
[3,]    1    7   15
[4,]    2    8   23

> unlist(aggregate(mat2, list(rep(1, nrow(mat2))), max)[-1])
V1 V2 V3 V4
 2  7 12 23
```

Comment: Good solution though of course they also internally use `*apply` (and there’s nothing wrong with that!). It’s maybe worth pointing out that `aggregate` isn’t defined for matrices, only for data.frames, so matrices get implicitly coerced, which is fairly expensive for large matrices.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes I agree. I don't recommend `aggregate` either. I added a `order` method, hope this looks and works more like the thing avoids `*apply`.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Why did you use col(mat)  in order? It seems to me that** order** sort in ascending order each column of mat and returns the indices of the elements...

Comment: @Childeric `col` ensures that the order is run by columns. If we use `row`, then we order values by row

Answer (score 2):

One possibility for sorting is to use `colSort` from `Rfast`:

```
Rfast::colSort(mat)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   -7   -4  -21
[2,]    0    3   12
[3,]    1    7   15
[4,]    2    8   23
```

We can also use `Rfast` to get the max for each column:

```
Rfast::colMaxs(mat2, value = TRUE)

[1]  2  7 12 23
```

Another option for sorting is to use a simple for loop:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(mat)){
  mat[,i] <- sort(mat[,i])
}
```

Could also use a simple for loop to get max:

```
max <- 0
for(i in 1:ncol(mat2)){
  max[i] <- max(mat2[,i])
}
```